# QGIS 3 does not show geometry tables with NULL geometries

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I just noticed that in QGIS 3 (3.0.1, Lubuntu 16.04 LTS), QGIS does not show tables in which the geometry column has all `NULL` values.

For example, I took a table `tt` with a geometry column `geom`, and

```
UPDATE tt SET geom = NULL;
```

Then if I refresh the QGIS connection, the table disappears. The 'geom' column looks as follows in `\d+ tt`:

```
                                     Table "public.tt"
 Column |   Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
--------+----------+-----------+----------+---------+----------+--------------+-------------
...
 geom   | geometry |           |          |         | main     |              |
```

Has anyone had similar issues?